Name of Comedian and Show/Special-Early 90s
Wondering if someone can help me figure this out. I remember a "show" (maybe a one time skit?) in the early 90s which I think* was on HBO. It was on a stage with a ton of props, one being a fake apartment building. 
It was like a one man show but the comedian played multiple characters. 
I seem to remember him running up and down some steps to jump into new character roles during the performance. For example, he would yell something down from the second level apartment window and run down to the "street' level to respond as a different character. 
This is all I remember, but it was hilarious and I am trying to find it. He wore different "costumes" that he could get in an out of exceedingly quickly. Ring a bell to anyone? Thanks for your help.

This sounds like a one-man show. Using that term in searches could help narrow down the possibilities, especially if it was for sure on a premium cable channel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/700_Sundays
Could it be Billy Crystal?

@WillowRex Wikipedia says "700 Sundays" wasn't performed until 2004.

Sounds like a John Leguizamo stand up special

@WillowRex Yeah, 700 Sundays is not it but thanks for the reply

Leguizamo did have a similar backdrop in one of his stand-up specials, but he stayed on the stage the whole time. And didn't really go in and out of characters, at least not with costume changes.

I remember him being a white guy with mid-length hair.  I remember in the skit he was a certain character that smoked cigarettes and in another role in the same skit he was an Asian dry-cleaner owner who said "No Tickey No Waskey." This was comedy performance on a stage with major stage props in the early 1990s. It was definitely a one man show and it was very impressive he played all of those characters and switched between them so quickly. I can't even remember how it was possible. I've googled every possible combination of these terms with no luck.

@JasonB You might want to add this information into your question :)

It's an HBO comedy special called "Nelson Schmelson", by Bob Nelson (see clip here - 

 )
